# understanding a statement in Weibel's "The K-book" about bisimplicial sets

Tags: simplicial-stuff, algebraic-k-theory

Here is a theorem from Weibel's [The K-book, Chapter IV](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eweibel/Kbook/Kbook.IV.pdf)

> Theorem 3.6.1. Let f : X → Y be a map of bisimplicial sets.
> (i) If each simplicial map $X_{p,∗} → Y_{p,∗}$ is a homotopy equivalence, so is BX → BY .
> (ii) If Y is the nerve of a category I (constant in the second simplicial coordinate),
> and $f^{−1}(i,_\bullet) → f^{−1}(j,_\bullet)$ is a homotopy equivalence for every i → j in I, then each
> $B(f^{−1}(i)) → BX → B(I)$ is a homotopy fibration sequence.

In the above statements what is the map $f^{-1}(i,_\bullet)\to f^{-1}(j,_\bullet)$ induced by $i\to j$?
I am assuming that $f^{-1}(i,_\bullet)$ is the pullback of the map $f:X\to Y$ along the map $\Delta^0\to Y$ corresponding to $i$.

Comment: Well, duh!  I made a mistake in citing the result.

Comment: The correct hypothesis for (ii) should be that X is the nerve of a

Comment: $I \int F$ for a functor $F(i)=f^{-1}(i)$. Then $i\to j$ gives $F(i)\to F(j)$

Comment: Thank you. In this part of the question, is considering them as bisimplicial sets needed?

Comment: Ok got it! F is a functor into the category of topological spaces